# onmouseover works in firefox but not chrome or safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, onmouseover

Well the question is pretty straight forward

For some reason the onmouseover events arent working in chrome (or safari yet to check IE). I have used onmouseover before and it worked fine, but not this time.

you can see the site I am trying to build here:

http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/test/demo.html

any help on this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `#screen` z-index to 0.  Then adjust the z-index on the `#top` and `#left` divs

Answer (score 2):

The event you want is mousemove not mouseover.

```
onmousemove
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp

Comment: im not sure this is what i want - can you explain why you think it might be what I am looking for? Thanks lastcoder

Comment: this isn't relevant to the original question but can you tell me why my website bounces when I load ajax content into the screen frame? I cant figure it out. thanks

Comment: @katie bekell - "onmousemove" is the w3c standard event you should be using, "onmouseover" was a Microsoft IE only event. It bounces because the location your loading to is being emptied and then filled again, so the page is re-rendering in that split second causing the bounce.

Comment: do you know how this can be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me in  Chrome and Safari, however the formatting was really bad in any IE below 9.

Comment: thanks dez the problem was resolved - im not too worried about ie < 9 bc its just for a friend and i dont think he cares thanks!